# url JSON in android

Tags: android, json

why if i run this source , error FAILED EXCEPTION Asynctask #2 Illegal character in url

this is source

```
Intent in = getIntent();
get_nama = in.getStringExtra(tag_nama);
get_subkategoris = in.getStringExtra(tag_subkategoris);
"http://tribinacita.esy.es/tribinacita/index.php/sikomando/tampil_lokasi/?";
url += "nama_lok="+get_nama+"&subkategoris="+get_subkategoris+"&is_android=1";
```

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: yes, and i find error FAILED EXCEPTION Asynctask #2 Illegal character in url

Comment: Double-check that the code you posted here is identical to the code yo u are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"http://tribinacita.esy.es/tribinacita/index.php/sikomando/tampil_lokasi/?";
```

This line of code is just a string literal that isn't assigned to a variable. If this is identical to the code you are actually running, then you need to add an assignment:

```
url = "http://tribinacita.esy.es/tribinacita/index.php/sikomando/tampil_lokasi/?";
```